# Как работает catman(8) UNIX/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, man

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем смысл работы catman(8) в UNIX-подобных системах? 
Понимаю есть man; понимаю файлы man, которые лежат в соответствующих каталогах; понимаю есть nroff, который эти файлы форматирует.

Но что дает catman(8) и что за зверь, к сожалению, не очень понятно из описания в руководстве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы докуменации должны
быть предварительно проиндексированы. Достигается это командой

```
catman -w
```

`Catman` - создает или обновляет уже отформатированные справочные страницы
`catman`  используется  для  создания  новейших  отформатированных справочных страниц, называемых cat страницами. `Cat` страницы, обычно, намного быстрее отображаются, чем исходные справочные страницы, но для их хранения требуется дополнительное место.

Решение о существовании определённых cat страниц принимает локальный администратор, который должен предоставить подходящие каталоги для их хранения.

В параметрах `catman` задаются иерархии справочных страниц и разделы, которые должны быть отформатированы заранее. Иерархиями по умолчанию считаются системные иерархии, указанные в файле настроек `man-db`, а  разделы  по умолчанию  берутся  из  значения  переменной  окружения `$MANSECT` (список значений через двоеточие) или из значения, заданного при компиляции man, если переменная окружения `$MANSECT` не установлена.

При указании `catman`
       списка имён разделов через пробельный символ, он заменит оба эти значения по умолчанию.
       При определении файлов для форматирования по каждой иерархии catman использует кэш базы данных index.

ПАРАМЕТРЫ

```
   -d, --debug
          Показывать отладочную информацию.

   -M путь, --manpath=путь
          Задаёт альтернативный путь поиска иерархии справочных страниц (указываются через двоеточие). По умолчанию, используются все пути, отмеченные как системные иерархии в файле настроек man-db.

   -C файл, --config-file=файл
          Использовать указанный пользовательский файл настройки вместо значения по умолчанию ~/.manpath.

   -?, --help
          Показать справочное сообщение и закончить работу.

   --usage
          Показать короткое сообщение об использовании и завершить работу.

   -V, --version
          Показать информацию о версии.
```